# how to use vlookup from 2 lookup value cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a table of names with their numbers and want to use vlookup formula to lookup a specific number from a cell from that table and return me the name as the result but if the specific number in that cell is not found then i want it to try another cell for example

Table has 2 column

Note employee code consist of 3 numbers and station number consist of 4 numbers

```
| Employee Code/Station Number # |  Name  |
|:------------------------------:|:------:|
| 123                            |  John  |
| 456                            | joseph |
| 3213                           |  jack  |
| 5656                           |  John  |
```

On the next sheet for the result I have 3 columns

```
| Employee Code | Employee Station No | Name |
|---------------|---------------------|------|
| 456           |                     |      |
|               | 3213                |      |
|               | 5656                |      |
| 123           |                     |      |
```

Now I need a vlookup formula which will first lookup in the employee code column if number is there then substitute the result but if employee code is empty then lookup in the employee station no and substitute the result

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(*employee code*, *TABLE*,2,false),VLOOKUP(*employee station no*, *TABLE*,2,false)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. If you don´t provide oone input sample and your expected output, you will get "generic" solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that the first table is `"Sheet1"` and the second table is `"Sheet2"` and the first cell on both tables is `A1`, try this one. (If not, just modified according to your data)

```
=IF(AND(A2<>"",B2=""),VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$12:$B$15,2,FALSE),IF(AND(A2="",B2<>""),VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!$A$12:$B$15,2,FALSE),"Check Data!!"))
```

The initial condition will check if there is value (any) in the Employee code but no Station and you will get your `VLOOKUP` there, if it is not the case, it will search by station and not employee. In the remaining scenarios (no data or Station and employee data) an error message is shown.

**EDIT**

If you want to receive a value when both cells have value then use:

```
=IF(A2<>"",VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$12:$B$15,2,FALSE),IF(B2<>"",VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!$A$12:$B$15,2,FALSE),"Check Data!!"))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it didnt...if a2 is filled it shows an error with N/A... but if b2 is filled it shows the correct answer but if both are filled it gives an incorrect answer

Comment: @Malcolm Dias. I already check this formula. Just need to custom to your excel datasheet. If the Employee code is there and there is no Station code, it will make a `VLOOKUP` by Employee code. If there is Station code and no Employee code, it will make a `VLOOKUP` by Station code. Remaining scenarios will return an Error message.

Comment: if both (employee code and work station) are filled, it should provide me the vlookup result ... Can that be possible ??

Comment: and is it possible if a2 b2 can be lookup in more than one worksheetsheet

Comment: I already edit the answer for your first request. Regarding the second one... How your Workbook looks like? How many sheets do you need to search in? It is possible but I need more information.

Comment: there are seven worksheet from which i need to check in ...all seven sheet consist of the same format

Comment: No way to place the formulas in consecutive columns?

Comment: actually no its a huge data consisting of  2,800,000 rows... it cannot be adjusted in one sheet

Comment: emailed it to you